# AVATAR Saving: "Compressing" multiple layered CSS div images into one file for download

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

I am building an avatar-generator for a PHP/MySQL site I am working on. It uses CSS to layer multiple .png files to create the background, body, facial expressions, etc. for a user's avatar. This I have covered.

I want to add a feature to my site that will allow the user to download their layered avatar "image" as one .jpg file. Is this even possible? I think I have seen this functionality before but can't recall the site where I saw this now.

Of course, I *could* come up with a series of pre-generated files that would cover all of the computations possible with my images, but with somewhere around 200 objects to choose from and a maximum of 10 layers of choices, the number of permutations possible is somewhere around 8.14702044**e+22**! Obviously, this is *possible* for me to do but I would be old and gray before completing the task!

Poking around the Internet has led me to believe there *might* be some way to "screen cap" - with what software and if it can capture a small section of the screen I don't know. Besides, would this bog down my site (which is currently running at top speed)?

I've searched through Stack Overflow for similar questions but didn't find anything that addresses my problem specifically. That said, I am not certain what to even search for (the precise terminology) as this concept of layering and saving as one image is foreign to me.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my own problem. It's not quite what I had in mind when planning this part of the project, but the end result will be close enough (with some other modifications).

I will implement html2canvas (http://html2canvas.hertzen.com) to take a screenshot of the user's avatar when they have pressed "Save". I will store the resultant image to my server and this will be their avatar. Their selected variable data will be stored in a database so that they can load up their avatar at a later date and make changes to it.

Comment: Storing a client-side generated image is a bad idea, what if a malicious user uploads porn or some other disturbing image ? Your approach is only acceptable for users to download their avatars. Since you say the avatars are generated using CSS, why can't you just use that to display them ? Instead of storing an image on your server, just store the positions and IDs of the CSS styles.

Comment: I want to make the image available to the user as a downloadable item that they can use for other purposes (like a Facebook profile photo). The user cannot upload any images at all. The image that is being created (and stored) is generated from a series of PNG files on the site that they've combined in layers. There is no upload function.